# group and take the top K for each prefix

Tags: java, mongodb

i have a mongoDB collection with documents in that format:

```
{ "_id":..., "word": 1, "Value": 235 }
{ "_id":..., "word": 2, "Value": 862 }
{ "_id":..., "word": 1, "Value": 16210 }
```

and i want to get the the k document with the biggest Value from words with same prefix. the db is huge(more then 1M documents) and it has to be able to work fast.
so its impossible to sort it every time (i tried it, it take a lot of time).

what can i do? (i work with java)

Comment: What did you try? Did you use the aggregation framework?

Comment: what does "words with same prefix" mean?  which documents above have the same prefix?

Comment: i dont know how to do it with aggregation framework.  @WiredPrairie

Comment: You should try. It's well documented.  Stackoverflow isn't for coding requests, it's to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

use merge sort to group them into different groups that have similar characteristics, so it is easier to categorize and look things up

i learned about merge sort in my CSCI142 class =)

you could also make a binary tree that has all of the different options as leaves, and sort through them that way. not sure how efficient this would be though

Comment: it have to be fast, i cant sort it